# Rails, Ransack, HABTM - Empty result when multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form with :

```
<%= f.collection_select :carburants_id_eq_all, Carburant.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
```

When I select only 1 Carburant, it's render me the result normaly, but if I select more than 1 Carburant, the result is empty.

Here's my form in 'index.html.erb' :

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title_cont, "Name contains" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title_cont %>

  <%= f.collection_select :carburants_id_eq_all, Carburant.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>

  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

My index action in my 'post_controller.rb':

```
def index
  @search = Post.search(params[:q])
  @posts = @search.result(distinct: true)
end
```

My post.rb, carburant.rb and category.rb model :

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :carburant_id, :post_id
  belongs_to :carburant
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :carburant_ids
  has_many :categories
  has_many :carburants, through: :categories
end

class Carburant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :categories
  has_many :posts, through: :categories
end
```

My DB shema :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130114004613) do
     create_table "carburants", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "name",       :limit => nil
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
     end

    create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
      t.integer  "post_id"
      t.integer  "carburant_id"
      t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
      t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
    end

    create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
     t.string   "title"
     t.text     "content"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

   create_table "recherches", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "carburant_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
   end
end
```

Thank you by advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I tried replacing :carburants_id_eq_all by :carburants_id_eq_any in my form just to test, and it work perfecly with the EQ_ANY predicate, but still not with the EQ_ALL.

Comment: You have `Carburant` twice listed in your models, and no `Category`.

Comment: Also, why do you have `:carburant_id` listed in the arguments to `attr_accessible` in your `Post` model? There is no `carburant_id` attribute on this model.

Comment: @shioyama: I correct somethings: Category.rb added, and attr_accessible in Post.rb, I removed :carburant_id, and just keep :carburant_ids.
In my Post model, I need to have :carburant_ids in the attr_accesible list, or I get error : "Can't mass assign protected attributes carburant_ids "

Comment: yes you should keep `carburant_ids`.